# creating a table in sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

I apologize in advance for asking such a basic question but I am new to SQlite3 and having trouble starting.  I am trying to build a database with one table.  I used the following code to build a table.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE mytable
         (start, end, score)''')
```

but whenever I try to update or access the table it seems that it doesnt exist or maybe it exists in a different database.  I also tried creating a table called example.mytable but I got the error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown database example

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Does the program this code is part of exit? When do you try to access the table?

Comment: Works for me. Show the code that tries to update or access the table.

Comment: I used this method and checked and the table did exist.  I closed the connection after doing conn.commit().  I then reopened it and the data was there and closed it.  The third time I tried to access it I received an error that the table doesn't exist- do I have to end with committing and closing every time?

Comment: what is your solution?

Answer (score 8):

I think that a commit is needed after inserts (schema changes such as new tables should automatically commit). I would suggest adding the full path to your database as well to make sure you are accessing the same location next time round.

Here is an extension on your code:

```
import sqlite3

def create():
    try:
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE mytable
                 (start, end, score)""")
    except:
        pass

def insert():
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable (start, end, score)
              values(1, 99, 123)""")

def select(verbose=True):
    sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
    recs = c.execute(sql)
    if verbose:
        for row in recs:
            print row

db_path = r'C:\Users\Prosserc\Documents\Geocoding\test.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
c = conn.cursor()
create()
insert()
conn.commit() #commit needed
select()
c.close()
```

Output:

```
(1, 99, 123)
```

After closing the program if I log onto the SQLite database the data is still there.

Answer (score 3):

```
import sqlite3;
import pandas as pd;

con=None

def getConnection():
    databaseFile="./test.db"
    global con
    if con == None:
        con=sqlite3.connect(databaseFile)
    return con

def createTable(con):
    try:
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Movie
                 (start, end, score)""")
    except Exception as e:
        pass

def insert(con):
    c = con.cursor()
c.execute("""INSERT INTO Movie (start, end, score)
          values(1, 99, 123)""")

def queryExec():
    con=getConnection()
    createTable(con)
    insert(con)
    # r = con.execute("""SELECT * FROM Movie""")
    result=pd.read_sql_query("select * from Movie;",con)
    return result


r = queryExec()
print(r)
```