# SQL: connecting to database with Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am completely new to `SQL` and I am trying to connect to a database with sqlite3. This database has a Browser-based access, but I would like to connect directly with a `Python` script. I can see that there is a wealth of material on `SQL` and `SQL` with `Python`, but I am struggling to understand what to do. I have the url of the database Browser-based access.

Which keywords shall I specify in the connect command in sqlite3?

Also, I was told that there are different flavours of `SQL` and one should use the version that is used on the target database, is this the case?

---

EDIT:

I have found out that `SQLite` cannot do this and one need to install `MySQL` for `python`.

Comment: Python's sqlite docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).  You should be able to connect with `conn = sqlite3.connect(url)` I think - see the docs for the [connect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837920/creating-a-table-in-sqlite3-python might help